# List of Array Functions can be used in Excel Like Sumproduct

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to know the functions which process multiple arrays in it.
Can you update me from the list of the functions which works on arrays.
Like Sumproduct.

Thanks

Comment: I asked the same question here:  http://superuser.com/questions/1064273/which-worksheet-functions-can-return-an-array  It appears that most will work....some like `Cell()` will not.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
=correl
=mmult
=t.test
=f.test
=covariance.p
=ttest
=ftest
=covar
=covariance.s
=pearson
=sumproduct
```

Comment: Thanx Dan.  But I am looking for the functions which can be used in my Accounting Data and these functions you mentioned above are mostly maths functions and these didn't help me. If you have any other functions which can be used to perform some calulations on the basis of criteria, to extract a word from a string, to concatenate data or something else.  I already aware from the basic functions like sumif, left, mid, right, and many more. I just want to know is there any **advance** functions for these processes mentioned above.  Kindly update me if you can solve my query.

Comment: I would use the 'insert function' just above the worksheet. It's the button that says 'fx'. There is a search box at the top of the window that pops up. You can normally use this to find a function that does what you need. I am struggling to work out what you actually need. You are looking for functions that work on arrays. Specifically accounting data. Then you say you want to manipulate text. Could you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?